# is there a booking form module with orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Is there a module available for a booking form?

Allowing you to see when something is available for hire and then recording your name for it?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. To be sure, please check Orchard Gallery: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine has created a demo of KendoUI's scheduler in his Kendo package on the gallery. It uses projections and is pretty flexible. May be somewhere you could start at least. His introduction to the module is here: http://breakoutdeveloper.com/Orchard-Modules/kendo-web-updates-q2-2013 and on the gallery here: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Kendo.Web/2013.2.716